# ¿Cómo estilar HTML inyectado por innerHtml?

Tags: angular, tailwind, innerhtml, markdown

Estoy haciendo una página web en **Angular** (y estilando con Tailwind) que lee noticias enviadas por una API creada con *Stripe*. La API envía las noticias en *markdown*, por lo que estoy usando `ngx-markdown` para transformarlas en HTML y usarlas en la plantilla de la siguiente manera (que es como sugiere la documentación):

```
<div [innerHTML]=" noticia?.attributes.contenido | markdown " id="noticia" class=""></div>
```

Lo cual, de hecho, me renderiza el contenido, pero como Tailwind limpia los estilos entonces todo el texto se junta y queda como si fueran párrafos nada más.

[image: Ejemplo del texto con títulos]

Ese texto es este texto:

```
# One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams.
One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself *transformed* in his bed into a horrible  [vermin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vermin "Wikipedia Vermin"). He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff sections. The bedding was hardly able to cover **strong** it and seemed ready to slide off any moment. His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, link waved abouthelplessly as he looked. <cite>“What's happened to me?”</cite> he thought. It wasn't a dream. His room, a proper human room although a little too small, lay peacefully between its four familiar walls.</p>

## The bedding was hardly able to cover it.

It showed a lady fitted out with a fur hat and fur boa who sat upright, raising a heavy fur muff that covered the whole of her lower arm towards the viewer a solid fur muff into which her entire forearm disappeared..

### Things we know about Gregor's sleeping habits.

- He always slept on his right side.
- He has to get up early (to start another dreadful day).
- He has a drawer and a alarm clock next to his bed.
- His mother calls him when he gets up to late.


<table class="data">
  <tr>
    <th>Writer</th>
    <th>Nationality</th>
    <th>Genre</th>
    <th>Most famous book</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Franz Kafka</td>
    <td>Leo Tolstoy</td>
    <td>F. Scott Fitzgerald</td>
    <td>H.G. Wells</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Austrian</td>
    <td>Russia</td>
    <td>American</td>
    <td>British</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Literature & Fiction, Philosophy, Short Stories</td>
    <td>Literature & Fiction, Philosophy</td>
    <td>Literature & Fiction, Short Stories</td>
    <td>Science Fiction</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>The Metamorphosis</td>
    <td>War & Piece</td>
    <td>The Great Gatsby</td>
    <td>War of the Worlds</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

El cual como pueden ver tiene títulos, links y cosas que enriquecen el texto y hacen que la noticia sea leíble. Al estilar en css no funciona. Claramente no puedo estilar con Tailwind porque en ningún momento veo las etiquetas, su llenado pasa ya cuando se llama a la API, por lo que tampoco puedo estilar así.
Creo que no se puede estilar, pero vengo aquí a ver si hay alguien que tenga alguna idea de cómo puedo solucionarlo :( muchas gracias de antemano a todos los que leyeron hasta aquí.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por si a alguien le sucede lo mismo, tuve que resolver creando mi propio lector de markdown y metiendo en las etiquetas las clases de Tailwind que quería utilizar para cada etiqueta:

```
markdownToHtml(markdown: string): string {
let html = markdown;
// Reemplaza los títulos de Markdown con etiquetas HTML correspondientes
html = html.replace(
  /^#\s+(.*)$/gm,
  '<h1 class="mt-4 mb-2 font-bold text-2xl" >$1</h1>'
);
html = html.replace(
  /^##\s+(.*)$/gm,
  '<h2 class="my-2 font-bold text-xl" >$1</h2>'
);
html = html.replace(
  /^###\s+(.*)$/gm,
  '<h3 class="my-2 font-bold italic" >$1</h3>'
);
html = html.replace(/^####\s+(.*)$/gm, '<h4 class="font-bold" >$1</h4>');
html = html.replace(/^#####\s+(.*)$/gm, '<h5 class="font-bold" >$1</h5>');
html = html.replace(/^######\s+(.*)$/gm, '<h6 class="font-bold" >$1</h6>');

// Reemplaza los énfasis y negritas de Markdown con etiquetas HTML correspondientes
html = html.replace(/\*\*(.*)\*\*/g, '<strong>$1</strong>');
html = html.replace(/__(.*)__/g, '<strong>$1</strong>');
html = html.replace(/\*(.*)\*/g, '<em>$1</em>');
html = html.replace(/_(.*)_/g, '<em>$1</em>');

// Reemplaza los enlaces de Markdown con etiquetas HTML correspondientes
html = html.replace(
  /\[(.*)\]\((.*)\)/g,
  '<a href="$2" class="underline underline-offset-1 after:block after:text-negro after:content-link after:w-[20px] after:h-[20px]"  >$1</a>'
  );
  
  // Reemplaza los saltos de línea de Markdown con etiquetas HTML <br>
  html = html.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
  html = html.replace(/<br>\s*<table/gi, '<table');

// Convierte las listas
html = html.replace(/^(\s*)[*+-] (.*)$/gm, function (match, spaces, item) {
  let bullet = '<li class="before:block before:text-negro before:content-[] before:w-[20px] before:h-[20px] pl-2">' + item + '</li>';
  if (spaces.length > 0) {
    return spaces.replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;') + '<ul>' + bullet + '</ul>';
  } else {
    return '<ul>' + bullet + '</ul>';
  }
});
// Agrupar todos los elementos li en un solo ul
html = html.replace(/<\/ul>\s*<ul>/g, '');

// Reemplaza dos o más <br> seguidos por solo uno
html = html.replace(
  /<br\s*\/?>\s*(<br\s*\/?>)+/g,
  '<div class="block w-full h-3"></div>'
);

//Agrega clase text-left a los th
html = html.replace(/<th([^>]*)>/g, '<th$1 class="text-left">');

// Elimina <br> debajo de títulos
html = html.replace(/(<h\d>.*?<\/h\d>)\s*<br\s*\/?>/g, '$1');


// Agrega las etiquetas <p> al principio y al final del texto
html = '<article>' + html + '</article>';

return html;}
```

Cada línea toma lo anterior, busca con la RegEx y lo que coincide lo reemplaza por el segundo parámetro (la etiqueta correspondiente).